# How can I list colors in WPF with XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I get list of all colors I can pick in Visual Studio Designer (which is `System.Windows.Media.Colors`, but that isn't a collection) and put them into my own `ComboBox` using WPF and XAML markup?

Comment: Similar to CasperOne's suggestion, here's a way to do it all in XAML, with a nice display of everything in a WrapPanel. http://stuff.seans.com/2011/02/14/creating-a-listbox-that-shows-all-predefined-wpf-colors/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is the pure XAML solution.

In your resources section, you would use this:

```
<!-- Make sure this namespace is declared so that it's in scope below -->
.. xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" ..

<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType" 
    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
            Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"  
    MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Or, as [CodeNaked points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562682/how-can-i-list-colors-in-wpf-with-xaml/562840#comment9495865_562840), it can be reduced to one tag:

```
<ObjectDataProvider 
    ObjectInstance="{x:Type Colors}" 
    MethodName="GetProperties" 
    x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp" />
```

And then the combobox would look like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

Comment: @casperOne - Your solution can be condensed down to one line: `<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{x:Type Colors}" MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp" />`. This answer is fairly old, so maybe it didn't work at the time. But i tested with a .NET 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0 project and it worked everytime.

Comment: @casperOne if i want to do `SelectedItemBinding ` what type must the value be?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a great ItemTemplate to use for a combobox using [casperOne's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562682/how-can-i-list-colors-with-wpf/562840#562840):

```
<ComboBox Name="cboColors"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}"
          SelectedValuePath="Name">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18" Margin="0,0,0,2">
              <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" 
                  BorderBrush="Black" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="{Binding Name}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
           </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I have done in a past ASP.net app:

```
// populate colors drop down (will work with other kinds of list controls)
Type colors = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
PropertyInfo[] colorInfo = colors.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.Static);
foreach ( PropertyInfo info in colorInfo)
{
    ddlColor.Items.Add(info.Name);                
}

// Get the selected color
System.Drawing.Color selectedColor = 
    System.Drawing.Color.FromName(ddlColor.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in code using reflection.  The following will dump all predefined WPF color names to Output:

```
using System.Reflection;

void ListAllColors()
{
    Type colorsType = typeof(System.Windows.Media.Colors);
    PropertyInfo[] colorsTypePropertyInfos = colorsType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    foreach (PropertyInfo colorsTypePropertyInfo in colorsTypePropertyInfos)
        Debug.WriteLine(colorsTypePropertyInfo.Name);
}
```

And to put them in a combobox, you could simply change the last line to:

```
_comboBox.Items.Add(colorsTypePropertyInfo.Name);
```